# Can't send selected table data to DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I can't understand the problem in my code. I want that when user selects a table name it would be shown on datagridView. But I can't send my data to dataTable. When I'm debugging dt variable is null. What I'am missing?

Here is the code I have been written so far:

```
        public void ShowSelectedTable(string tableName, DataGridView grid, string   dbFilePath) 
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
            dbConn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dbFilePath;
            dbConn.Open();

            dbSet = new DataSet();
            dbAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dbAdapt.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select * From " + tableName + ";", dbConn);
            dbAdapt.Fill(dbSet);
            dt = dbSet.Tables["TableName"];
            grid.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick guess -

maybe go from

```
dt = dbSet.Tables["TableName"];
```

to

```
dt = dbSet.Tables[tableName];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :) I tried to change it but it doesn't work. It still shows that dt (DataTable) is null.

Comment: Problem solved ! I forgot to write tableName in this line : dbAdapt.Fill(dbSet, tableName);